# Azure Serverless SQL will not pause due to Azure service queries keeping it online

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql

There is a database we use for archiving old data which I want to be 'serverless' so that it only fires up when we make a query.

I changed the size from standard to serverless without issues. I have not connected to this DB since making the change.

However it doesn't pause despite setting the auto-pause to 1 hour.

Looking in Query Performance Insight, I can see there is a query which regularly polls the DB for size information... every hour at least.

`(@type int)SELECT file_id, name, size AS size_8KB, max_size AS max_size_8KB, ISNULL(FILEPROPERTY(name, 'SpaceUsed'), size) AS space_used_8KB FROM sys.database_files WHERE type = u/type ORDER BY size DESC`

If Azure SQL Serverless thinks the DB is in use because Azure services are polling the DB several times an hour to get information, it'll never auto pause?

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you work out the source of this query in the end? I'm having a very similar problem, with a query that appears to be checking database size and the database not auto-pausing.

Comment: yes. stupidly, when you navigate to the database in the Azure web portal, it sends a query to the database, keeping it alive each time. The trick (for us at least) is leave it alone and don't keep checking on it.

Comment: Thank you. That's very helpful. Now to track down whoever is leaving the portal open 24/7

Answer (score 0):

Azure SQL Serverless "thinks" the DB is in use because the DB is in use!

You did a good investigation and you even found the query that is using it. Good!

Azure SQL Database Serverless will not pause if it keeps receiving requests.

So the solutions are:

- Find who is making that request and stop it
- Maybe serverless is not the right option for you and you can move to some S* plan